# Rename drf_spectacular API end points

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm using **drf_spectacular** with Django Rest Framework to **generate API documentation**. However, I need to **customize the names** of the **endpoints** displayed in the Spectacular API documentation.

**Could someone please advise on how to achieve this? Thank you!**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgwCi.png)

I try see SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS but didn't find something usefull